# Passing Form Data to View

Tags: python, django

I have the following view:

views.py

```
def PackingListView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PackingListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if 'preview' in request.POST:
                request.session['data'] = form.cleaned_data
                return redirect('myview')
  ....
```

I would like to take the data in `form` and pass it to this next view, and set the `data` variable equal to it.  This was previously working, but once I added a foreign key into this form, the session no longer works as it is not serializable. What approach is the safest for me to take here?

views.py

```
class myview(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = request.session.pop('data', {})#this won't work  now

        pdf = render_to_pdf('packlist_preview.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

Also in case it is needed - here is the URL for `myview`

```
url(r'^myview/', views.myview.as_view(), name='myview'),
```

Comment: You could replace the instance in the cleaned data (e.g. `'relatated_obj': <RelatedObject pk:15>`) with its pk (e.g. `'related_object_id: 15`). Then fetch the object again in the next view. If you need a more general solution, you might be able to use the `FormWizard` from [`django-formtools`](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#module-formtools.wizard.views), or at least look at it for inspiration.

Comment: Hi Alasdair- could you possibly expand on the solution you mentioned in an answer? I’m not sure I’m fully following your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to serialize the data if you replace the model instance with its id.

```
data = form.cleaned_data
# remove object from data dict
related_object = data.pop('related_object')
# add in a reference
data['related_object_id'] = related_object.pk
# now you should be able to serialize object
request.session['data'] = data
```

Then in the next view, you can fetch the object from the database using its id

```
data = request.session.pop('data', {})
related_object_id = data.pop('related_object_id', None)
if related_object_id:
    try:
        data['related_object'] = RelatedObject.objects.get(pk=related_object_id)
    except RelatedObject.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```